# Mongoose Validation Error : Invalid schema configuration

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i make a Schema in mongoose and when i start node it crash

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { DataView } = require("webidl-conversions");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"Please Enter Product Name"],
        trim:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"Please Enter Product Description"]
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,"Please Enter Product Price"],
        maxLength:[6,"Price cannot exceed 6 characters"]
    },
    rating:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    images:[
        {
            public_id:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
            },
            url:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
            }
        }
    ],
    category:{
        category:String,
        required:[true,"Please Enter Product Category"],
    },
    stock:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,"Please Enter Product Stock"],
        maxLength:[4,"stock cannot excee 4 characters"],
        default:1
    },
    numOfReviews:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    reviews:[
        {
            name:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
            },
            rating:{
                type:Number,
                required:true,
            },
            comment:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
            }

        }
    ],
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})

mosule.export = mongoose.model("Product",productSchema);
```

this is my schema code and i get TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: Could not determine the embedded type for array `category.required`. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition for more info on supported schema syntaxes this error i don't know what is wrong so please help me,
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

based on what am seeing here, it seems the ways you are exporting your module is the one giving you problem.

Instead of `module.exports`, you wrote `mosule.export`

Check it out

Answer (score 1):

```
category:{
        category:String,
        required:[true,"Please Enter Product Category"],
    }
```

if you want an array of catagory then you can use this

```
category:{
        type: Array,
        required:[true,"Please Enter Product Category"],
    }
```